# Use keras pad_sequences in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have a pandas data frame which contains word indexes.

```
    id  seq                          int_sequence
0   111 cat over dog                 [2, 7, 3]
1   222 hello silly dog cat from     [6, 9, 3, 2, 5]
2   333 biscuit sandwich food        [1, 8, 4]
```

I am now trying to pad the sequences with zeros to the max length.

```
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(df.int_sequence, maxlen=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, padding='post', value=0)
```

Which returns a numpy array of shape (3,5) - following which I am using the below transformation to convert the numpy array into a `df` and join back to the original df:

```
df_padded_sequences = pd.DataFrame({ 'padded_seq': padded_sequences.tolist()})
```

Whilst it works, it feels hacky - so I would like to `pad_sequences` in situ on the pandas df mainly so I am not worried about any of the orders breaking and therefore changing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I have made it work! Happy to hear any better solutions though...

```
df['padded_sequences'] = pad_sequences(df.int_sequence, maxlen=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, padding='post', value=0).tolist()
```

Converting the numpy array to a list.